# promise resolution order and await

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, promise, async-await

I've got this piece of code:

```js
af = async () => {
    Promise.resolve()
    .then(x => console.log("first then"))
    .then(x => console.log("second then"))
    await Promise.resolve()
    console.log("after await")
}

af()
```

In Google Chrome Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)
when I run it from a `<script>`, I got the following results:

```
first then 
after await
second then
```

but when I copy/paste the code into the console and run it, I've got:

```
first then
second then
after await
```

node.js 8.5.0 behaves similarly.

What is the proper order and why there's a difference?

// edit

another interesting thing is that firefox 55.0.2 (64-bit)
for this code:

```js
af = async () => {
    Promise.resolve()
    .then(x => console.log("first then"))
    .then(x => console.log("second then"))
    .then(x => console.log("third then"))
    .then(x => console.log("forth then"))
    await Promise.resolve()
    console.log("after await")
}

af()
```

logs:

```
first then
second then
third then
after await
forth then
```

Comment: If the precise order of multiple `.then()` handlers that are all in the queue at the same time matters (and code after an `await` is pretty much the same as a `.then()` handler), then your code should be written such that you control the order yourself rather than you rely exactly on how the promise scheduler orders them.  And, I'm not even sure what you've asked is actually written into specification.  Most real implementations would have async operations behind the promises that have indeterminate timing anyway.

Comment: An exact, precise answer to this will be most likely be extremely long and depend on unspecified implementation details. Look at the steps for DOMContentLoaded, for example https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-end

Comment: Don't really know why, but it may be a tip: 
If you replace all you logs with an array push and then log your final array, the order is always
['1 then', '2 then', 'await]
maybe a console.log inconsistent behaviour ?

Comment: I can even get different behavior in Chrome depending on whether the debugger is open when the script runs. That's a big clue to me that the order really doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this is adding a `await` before the `Promise.resolve()` that does the "first then" and "second then" console logs. That way it'll wait for that promise to be done before it moves on to the console log for "after wait"

This is how you're meant to do it.

```js
af = async () => {
    await Promise.resolve() // NOTE: I added a "await" before the Promise.resolve()
    .then(x => console.log("first then"))
    .then(x => console.log("second then"))
    await Promise.resolve()
    console.log("after await")
}

af()
```

Comment: I didn't ask for a way to make both `then`s to be resolved before bottom console.log. I want to know scheduling algorithm for this case (`await` before second `then` callback or after?)

Comment: What do you mean by a scheduling algorithm?

Comment: rules that dictate the order in which callbacks are added to the message queue

Comment: Ah right I think I get you. `await` is supposed to be called before the second `then` callback but honestly it just depends on your processing time. The first promise and `await` are called at the same time so if the first `then` finishes instantly and `await` takes really long then the second `then` will come before the `await`. When you run commands like that though its almost like you're running them in two process queues.

Comment: The first promise will be in one process queue and the `await` will be in another one so they won't be waiting on each other to finish, they will both be running at the same time there is no real order and they won't really wait for one task to finish to start another. There is no waiting or real queue/order.

Comment: all promise callbacks in the example are synchronous - they will be executed immediately in the same tick. There's no time factor here.