# How to do asynchronous programming / api call and handle multiple promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

- In javascript / react how we can call multiple dependent api where new call request payload have previous call response value.
- I have a setup in database where request param name and api end point are been stored
- Asynchronous how we can do dependent api call where number of api call / chain of call is not fix to get the final response, it is as per configuration in my database
- kindly give me a code example / pseudo code

```
  var finalResult;

    const getData =  (url1, url2) => {
        // Make the first API call to url1
        fetch(url1)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data1 => {
                const userId = data1.userId;
                const url2WithUserId = `${url2}?userId=${userId}`;
                return fetch(url2WithUserId);
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data2 => {
                console.log("Final Result:", data2);
                finalResult = data2;
                //at the beginning finalResult is empty/null , but how i can rerender component / root level code once final result set form last api call
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });
    }

    // I can read here my setup form database here
    const apiURL1 = 'https://api.example.com/data1';
    const apiURL2 = 'https://api.example.com/data2';

   // i have all the setup, now how i can pass multiple dynamic params and its assicuate url here, may be i need to pass a object array to loop all the api url but how will be the dependent api call
    getData(apiURL1, apiURL2);
```

Comment: if there is a dependent element in your function I would add async/await commands to getData. [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254408/promise-resolution-order-and-await)

Comment: what is the issue you are having with the code you've presented?

Comment: @Jaromanda X, currently  what i try its fixed 2 successive call. but i need n number of dependent api call . but dont know to change my code for dynamic n number of call

Comment: well, if call `n` depends on call `n-1` (like it does here) there's really no shortcuts, since it is unlikely that the relationship between successive "dynamic" calls is going to be identical

Comment: @willwrighteng , thank you so much for your comment . i saw the example but i need dynamic n number of call , dont know how to update my code to achieve this

Comment: @Jaromanda X, thank you. all my api end point and param name is not identical , i can read it from a db setup before calling first api. problem is how i can do dynamic .then().then() . . .n. here only identical is all are get request

Comment: yes, that'sright

Comment: @Jaromanda X could you please help me by posting an answer with a code example / pseudo code. Or kindly give me a upvode so that other can interest to answer

Comment: Sure, why not. What's the answer you're expecting?

Comment: kindly give an example how we can chain n number of fetch call. here n > 0